# Passing job array index as an argument in drmaa-python

Tags: python, lsf, drmaa

I am using a lsf-drmaa implementation and interfacing through drmaa-python. I usually pass in the environment variable, $LSB_JOBINDEX, into my run.sh script as an argument. Through drmaa-python, I created `JobTemplate jt` and would like to pass it through as an argument. I have tried using PARAMETRIC_INDEX, but this command does not work for me: `jt.args = [str(drmaa.JobTemplate.PARAMETRIC_INDEX)]`.

I receive the following error:

```
W #29c0 [  1227.22]  * '$drmaa_incr_ph$' can not be expanded in '$drmaa_incr_ph$'; removing from string
```

Where am I going wrong and/or how can I pass in the index using another method? Thanks--

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference (within your run script) the value of `PARAMETRIC_INDEX` via the environment variable `$SGE_TASK_ID`. *qmaster* takes care of expanding/populating the `$SGE_TASK_ID` with each array index value in your script when it submits the corresponding job.